# Why does all points $(x,y)$ satisfying $ax+by=c$ stay on a straight line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, analytic-geometry

We know that points $(x_i,y_i)$ which satisfy the equation $ax_i+by_i=c$ lie on the same straight line. I understand that all points on this line satisfy the equation, but how do we ensure that **all** points satisfying the equation stay on the same line?

As @saulspatz says,

> How do we know that the lines defined by analytic geometry satisfy the Euclidean axioms?

Comment: It'd be helpful to think in terms of the slope.

Comment: If $a,b$ are not both zero, then $ax+by=c$ is the equation of a line.  This means: the set of **all** solutions **is** the line.

Comment: @blue Please elaborate!

Comment: What is your definition of a "straight line", for a start?

Comment: As GEdgar said, one way to think about it is that it is a line by definition. If you want something else, you should first tell us what do you mean by line, i.e. give us definition you want to consider.

Comment: @ennar Why does all points on the line satisfy the equation?

Comment: @Ennar To put it another way...

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you are asking how we know that the lines defined by analytic geometry satisfy the Euclidean axioms?

Comment: @saulspatz Absolutely yes mate!

Comment: Please edit your question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ax+by=c$$

If $a \ne 0$, then we have $x  =\frac{c-by}a$. Knowing $y$ completely determines $x$. Let $y$ takes value $t$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{c}{a}\\0\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{b}{a}\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The locus is parallel to the direction of $\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{b}{a} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ and passes through the point $\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{c}{a}\\0\end{bmatrix} $. Since it moves along a direction, it is a line.

If $a=0$ and $b\ne 0$, then $y=\frac{c}{b}$ and $x$ can takes any values, this is clearly a horizontal line.